# Visual Studio 2017 c# console project does not provide namespace win32.registry

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I noticed that when you create a VS 2017 C# console project and try to access the

`Microsoft.Win32.Registry`

class, it seems not to be part of the references. As it is part of `mscorlib.dll` it should. Adding `mscorlib.dll` as a reference results - obviously - in double definition of basic types.

Even better: Do the same thing in VB (console project, use the Registry class) and it works right away...

Is it me or is this a bug in VS2017??

**--- Edited ---**

The code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

public class GetDotNetVersion
{
    public static void Get45PlusFromRegistry()
{
    const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\";

    using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(subkey))
    {
        if (ndpKey != null && ndpKey.GetValue("Release") != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(".NET Framework Version: " + CheckFor45PlusVersion((int)ndpKey.GetValue("Release")));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(".NET Framework Version 4.5 or later is not detected.");
        }
    }
}

// Checking the version using >= will enable forward compatibility.
private static string CheckFor45PlusVersion(int releaseKey)
{
    if (releaseKey >= 394802)
        return "4.6.2 or later";
    if (releaseKey >= 394254)
    {
        return "4.6.1";
    }
    if (releaseKey >= 393295)
    {
        return "4.6";
    }
    if ((releaseKey >= 379893))
    {
        return "4.5.2";
    }
    if ((releaseKey >= 378675))
    {
        return "4.5.1";
    }
    if ((releaseKey >= 378389))
    {
        return "4.5";
    }
    // This code should never execute. A non-null release key should mean
    // that 4.5 or later is installed.
    return "No 4.5 or later version detected";
}
}
// Calling the GetDotNetVersion.Get45PlusFromRegistry method produces 
// output like the following:
//       .NET Framework Version: 4.6.1

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetDotNetVersion.Get45PlusFromRegistry();
    }
 }
}
```

It is a .netCoreApp 1.1 ...

I get error CS0246 (Type or namespace *RegistryKey* not found) and subsequent errors (4 altogether).

VS also hints that the using directive for Microsoft.Win32 is obsolete.

Thanks!!

Comment: what kind of console application? .net cor?

Comment: It's not a bug. This is a BCL class, not a feature of Visual Studio. Either you created a .NET Core project or there is a typo in your code. Post a *reproducible* example

Comment: Here is the code:

Answer (score 0):

You do have a reference to Microsoft.Win32 in your code, and try accessing GetValue (or other method) using the Registry class (eg Registry.GetValue())

Registry is a [static class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core is cross platform, so Windows only things such as registry access are not recommended.

If you do want it, use NuGet package manager to add Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey package,

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/